# Site content type changes are not propagated to inheriting list content types

Tags: office-365, csom

I have the following situation:

- I've created several site columns en site content types
- I've created several sub webs with list, inheriting these content types

I assumed that if I updated the site content types it would be propagated to all inheriting content types. Now sometimes this is the case, but more often the changes are not propagated to the inheriting content types.

Both changes done manually and through CSOM are not propagated. The content type that I have the most issue with is based on a task content type.

If I create a new library with the content type, all is well. This new library inherits the right settings.

I have a dev and test/production in two tenants and three site collections. On test and production I have about 250 webs, inheriting these content types. I have these issue in both dev, test and production. So it's not unique to one tenant or site collection. I'm using Office365.

Does anybody have any experience with this, and knows how to solve and/or prevent this issue.

Comment: if you go to the edit page of one of your content types, go to advanced settings, what have you configured there?

Comment: If you're looking for the setting to push down the changes, it's set. I mostly use CSOM to make the changes and most of the time it works. So it doesn't seem to be a setting.

Answer (score 0):

Content type propagation is a bit of a messy scene.  In general however, if you add a column to your site content type it will not be added to the list content type.  However, if you add the new column into your list, it WILL detect that it's part of the existing content type and add it appropriately.

Comment: This is not wat I'm experiencing. If I add a column it is added most of the times. The main issue I have is with column order and column names.

Comment: Do you have items in the list using the content type when the columns ARE propagated?  I have also found that the scenario I described is true only after you have items in the list using the content type.

Comment: That's something I'm going to test. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok. just having items in a list is not enough. There is something else as well.